# Is there a way of redirecting a user to a SmartFolder?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We have a system of **SmartFolders** set up with various permissions set. The users can access the documents within their SmartFolders and have certain permissions granted to them( eg. Contributer ) as well as the permission to execute a custom action. Upon executing a custom action, the permissions previuosly granted to them would be revoked, so what we want to do is to automatically redirect the user to the SmartFolder they have access to. We use SDK 4.0.

Comment: If you use javascript for custom action instead of java then redirection is possible.

Comment: I use java. After custom action i should only redirect the user to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting the user to a smartFolder available for him, why don't you redirect him to the root of the site's "documentLibrary". By doing this, the user would see, in this page, all the smartFolders it can access.
I imagine that it would be more simple to determine the root of the document library instead of any smartFolders with some rights...?

Comment: TODIV, thank You for the suggestion. No matter on which location we choose to redirect, how redirection can be done from action code. Do You have a code example You could share with me?

Comment: The code will depend on your "custom action". If it's a Java or Javascript CODE. You will easily find on internet how to code a page redirection with both of these languages.
To not hard code the site's document library, you will have to search with Alfresco API (Java or Javascript) the right NodeRef : the one of the current site or the one of any site the user can join. You also can redirect to the dashboard of the user, it would be more simple to build URL.

Here is the Alfresco Java API : https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/java-public-api-list.html
And here is the Javascript one : https

Comment: Todiv did you look at the post below. Do you have an example of this to share with me.

Comment: if you use javascript then you can redirect.I dont think in java you can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried in numerous ways to achieve redirecting the user without success. 
Our main source material were Alfresco tutorials made by Jeff Potts (https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html ). We customize Alfresco with Java and implement our custom actions with the CustomDocLib action within a custom java class which extends the ActionExecutorAbstractBase class. We have found it hard to implement a redirect as a part of our previously customized actions, so it would also be helpful if there is a way for us to trigger the redirect after a certain action is performed.

This is how our current action (without redirect) is implemented:

**public class ReviewSigning extends ActionExecuterAbstractBase {

...**

**@Override
protected void executeImpl(final Action action, final NodeRef actionedUponNodeRef) {**

...

**serviceRegistry.getNodeService().setProperty(actionedUponNodeRef,QNameDef.....;**

...

**//REDIRECT TO HOMEPAGE OR SITE

    }**

If You would be kind enough to send us a code snippet or change ours so we could redirect our users, it would be much appreciated.